# How to center a div in small screen or extra small using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4, and i want div in center in extra small(xs) devices.
Have a look at this

[image: center a div]

As you can see those 2 content are in left, i want those 2 div in center in xs devices.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Luxo</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <link rel="stylsheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css">
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lora:ital@0;1&family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" type="text/css">
        </head>
        <body>

            <footer class="footer-section bg-dark">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <img src="images/footer-logo.png" alt="footer-logo">
                            <p class="d-inline">All Rights Reserved.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline mb-0 mt-3 float-md-right float-sm-right">
                                <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="images/fb-icon.png" alt="bf-icon"></a></li>
                                <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="images/tw-icon.png" alt="tw-icon"></a></li>
                                <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="images/dr-icon.png" alt="dr-icon"></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably need to do it through CSS and add a new class to HTML. Try to add the following CSS code in your css file without the `<style>` tags or in your html with the `<style>` tags:

```
<style>
    @media only screen and (max-width: 578px) {
      .credits {
        text-align:center;
      }
    }
</style>
```

and add `credits` class to the surrounding div like so:

```
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 credits">
                    <img src="images/footer-logo.png" alt="footer-logo">
                    <p class="d-inline">All Rights Reserved.</p>
                </div>
```

P.S. The 578px in the CSS is the default bootstrap xs width.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. Now i understand that at some point i need to use media queries, can't be dependent on B4 classes all the time.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using bootstrap 4, there are no class with `col-xs-*` in it, instead you can just use `col-*` for example `col-4` to span a column for 4 width grid on extra small devices.

Secondly as all the content in these two columns the content is `inline` so you can center it using `text-align:center;` easily on main div in media`query for small screen like:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  .footer-section {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, appreciated! :)

Comment: Happy to help bro

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `col-12` in your `<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">`. Now when the screen is smaller than XS, they will be in the middle.